# STM32F4 Discovery board

Tags: stm32, st-link

I use STMCubeIDE for the STM32 Discovery board. I start STMCubeIDE and run code then it shows a popup window that there is no ST-Link detected, but I did connect my USB from MCU to the laptop.

I installed ST-Link and tried like everything but nothing seems to work.

How can I detect USB as ST-Link? If I search/refresh the device list in the STMCubeIDE, I cannot find my USB ST-Link connected?

OS: Linux Ubuntu 20.04

About LEDs on Discovery:

- LD7 and LD2 are on
- LD0 blinking
- LD1 LD3 LD5 LD6 - are going into a circle blinking, then they blink for few times together, and follow again that pattern

Comment: Did you read the Linux installation instructions how to make the USB work, and did you type in the commands to make the USB work?

Comment: @Justme I'm not sure what should i do to make the USB work?

Comment: You should read the installation instructions and perform the steps listed in the instructions to make it work.

Comment: @Justme not sure if I'm following you, can you provide some link for that?

Comment: Can you tell us what the LEDs on the Discovery board are doing? What colours, what patterns of blinking?

Comment: Installation instructions can be found on ST website where you downloaded the Linux install package. The instructions likely come with the install package too. Just read the CubeIDE install instructions how to get USB devices working.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Linux tool called 'stlink' that can be installed and used to detect ST-Link devices (e.g., the Discovery board). This tool will tell you about the ST-Link programmer and about the STM32 that it is connected to.

The source repo is here:

https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink

You may also be able to install it via a package manager.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Yes, I install stlink, if I go st-info --probe I get 
"Failed to parse flash type or unrecognized flash type
Found 0 stlink programmers" - so it obviously doesn't see the STM32 Discovery board 
About LEDs on Discovery
LD7 and LD2 are on 
LD0 blinking
LD1 LD3 LD5 LD6 - are going into a circle blinking, then they blink for few times together, and follow again that pattern

Comment: This answer will not help if the installation is not done as per the installation instructions for any program to be able to find the USB devices.

Answer (score 0):

In Cube Ide, you must activate the debug pins, otherwise it may not work.
Something like this:

[image: Debug activation in cube IDE]